# How to draw an overhanging beam in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, technical-drawing, stanli, beams

This image is what I want to draw. Is it possible to draw it in LaTeX itself or should I draw it in some other app and import it?
I have tried Tikz, I couldn't quite get it right.

[image: overhanging beam]

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SE. It will be easier to help you if you show us what you have tried in tikz. Which part is problematic for you? This one is certainly doable in tikz. Of course you can also import it if you are able to draw it in some application outside of tex.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your future questions, please provide some code you have tried and explain what abstract problem you are encountering with it.

That being said, here is a solution to draw your figure with TikZ

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
    \node[above left] at (A) {$A$};
    \coordinate (B) at (7, 0);
    \node[above right] at (B) {$B$};
    \coordinate (C) at (10, 0);
    \node[above right] at (C) {$C$};
    
    \draw (A) -- (C);
    \draw[Latex-] (A) -- ++(0, -1)
        node[below] {$R_A$};
    \draw[Latex-] (B) -- ++(0, -1)
        node[below] {$R_B$};
    \draw (C) -- ++(0, -1);
    \draw[Latex-] (C) -- ++(0, 1)
        node[above right] {$\SI{15}{\kilo\newton}$};
    
    \draw[Latex-Latex] ($(A) + (0, -.8)$) -- ($(B) + (0, -.8)$)
        node[midway, above] {$\SI{7}{\meter}$};
    \draw[Latex-Latex] ($(B) + (0, -.8)$) -- ($(C) + (0, -.8)$)
        node[midway, above] {$\SI{3}{\meter}$};
    
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,8} {
        \draw[thick] ({\x*7/9}, 0) arc (180:0:{7/18});
    }
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

yielding:

[image]

**EDIT**

For the missing arrow, you might need something like `\draw[Latex-] ({4*7/9}, {7/18}) -- ++(45:1) node[above right] {$\SI{10}{\kilo\newton\per\meter}$};`.

If you prefer having kN/m written, I let you look at the [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package documentation.

Comment: Thank You! In future I will make sure to include the code and be more specific.

Comment: @AdithGM ... and know how to upvote + how to accept an useful answer